# video is rotated when upload on youtube, Android

Tags: android, youtube, google-api

I trying to upload a video from SD-Card to youtube using android. I am using Google API for youtube upload. Video upload successfully but with rotation of 180 degree. I am using the following code-

```
YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService(Strings.YOUTUBE_CLIENT_ID,Strings.YOUTUBE_DEV_ID);
try{
    service.setUserCredentials("abc123@gmail.com", "ag23sjafaar");
} catch (AuthenticationException ex){
    Log.e("AuthenticationError",":"+ex.getMessage());
    return;
}

File videoFile = new File(Strings.VIDEO_PATH);
if(!videoFile.exists()){
    Log.e("FileUploadErr","FileNotFound");
    return;
}

String mimeType = "video/*";
String videoTitle = name;
VideoEntry newEntry = new VideoEntry();
YouTubeMediaGroup mg = newEntry.getOrCreateMediaGroup();
mg.addCategory(new MediaCategory(YouTubeNamespace.CATEGORY_SCHEME,"Travel"));
mg.setTitle(new MediaTitle());
mg.getTitle().setPlainTextContent(videoTitle);
mg.setKeywords(new MediaKeywords());
mg.getKeywords().addKeyword("Travel");
mg.setDescription(new MediaDescription());
mg.getDescription().setPlainTextContent(videoTitle);
MediaFileSource ms = new MediaFileSource(videoFile,mimeType);
newEntry.setMediaSource(ms);
try{
    VideoEntry createdEntry = service.insert(new URL(Strings.YOUTUBE_VIDEO_UPLOAD_URL), newEntry);      
} catch(ServiceException se){
    Log.e("UploadVideo",":" + se.getMessage());         
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Update:**
If I browse video from SD-card and upload on youtube using Emulator. It works fine.

Comment: i have tried the same code but it dint work for me...can u figure out the problem.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13392642/how-to-fix-connection-reset-exception-in-java

Comment: This was the issue with device. Using some other device it works fine. You can use the same code to upload video on youtube with your own username and password.