# YouTubeService crashes my Android app when trying to upload a video to YouTube

Tags: java, android, windows, upload, youtube-api

I tried to use YouTubeService to connect to Youtube and Upload a video but is crashes allready if if it reaches YouTubeService(Client_ID,Developer_Code)

I got some code from this Topic:
[video is rotated when upload on youtube, Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256455/video-is-rotated-when-upload-on-youtube-android)

```
YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService(Client_ID,Developer_key);
    try{
        service.setUserCredentials("bla@bla.com", "test1234");
    } catch (AuthenticationException ex){
        Log.e("AuthenticationError",":"+ex.getMessage());
        return;
    }
```

I got the Developer Key from the Product Dashboard, But I'am not really sure what the Client Id is (I've read somewhere that it can be a String you lik, but I chose the application Name from the Product Dashboard).

Rest of the Code:

```
File videoFile = new File(mSharedPreferences.getString("output_file", ""));
    if(!videoFile.exists()){
        Log.e("FileUploadErr","FileNotFound");
        return;
    }

    String mimeType = "video/*";
    String videoTitle = "name";
    VideoEntry newEntry = new VideoEntry();
    YouTubeMediaGroup mg = newEntry.getOrCreateMediaGroup();
    mg.addCategory(new MediaCategory(YouTubeNamespace.CATEGORY_SCHEME,"Travel"));
    mg.setTitle(new MediaTitle());
    mg.getTitle().setPlainTextContent(videoTitle);
    mg.setKeywords(new MediaKeywords());
    mg.getKeywords().addKeyword("Travel");
    mg.setDescription(new MediaDescription());
    mg.getDescription().setPlainTextContent(videoTitle);
    MediaFileSource ms = new MediaFileSource(videoFile,mimeType);
    newEntry.setMediaSource(ms);
    try{
        VideoEntry createdEntry = service.insert(new URL("http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads"), newEntry);      
    } catch(ServiceException se){
        Log.e("UploadVideo",":" + se.getMessage());         
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here are the errors:

```
   02-12 15:31:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(10012): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   02-12 15:31:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(10012): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
   02-12 15:31:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(10012):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2336)
   02-12 15:31:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(10012):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2731)
   02-12 15:31:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(10012):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9387)
   02-12 15:31:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(10012):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
   02-12 15:31:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(10012):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
   02-12 15:31:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(10012):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
   02-12 15:31:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(10012):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3694)
   02-12 15:31:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(10012):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   02-12 15:31:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(10012):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
   02-12 15:31:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(10012):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
   02-12 15:31:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(10012):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
   02-12 15:31:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(10012):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   02-12 15:31:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(10012): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   02-12 15:31:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(10012):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   02-12 15:31:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(10012):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
   02-12 15:31:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(10012):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2331)
   02-12 15:31:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(10012):     ... 11 more
   02-12 15:31:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(10012): Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: com.google.gdata.client.media.MediaService
   02-12 15:31:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(10012):     at com.atino.bla.ytUpload.uploadToYoutube(ytUpload.java:111)
   02-12 15:31:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(10012):     at com.atino.bla.ytUpload.testMethode(ytUpload.java:58)
   02-12 15:31:29.492: E/AndroidRuntime(10012):     ... 14 more
```

Anyone an idea how to solve this problem?